# Metamask SDK window is not defined on nextjs

Tags: metamask, javascript, ethers.js, react, bsc

I`m trying to integrate Metamsk SDK to my Dapp, but when implementing the steps on the basic tutorial of their documentation I get the Reference error related to window, here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

import MetaMaskSDK from "@metamask/sdk";

const options = {
  injectProvider: false,
  checkInstallationImmediately: true,
  preferDesktop: false,
};

export default function Document() {

  const MMSDK = new MetaMaskSDK(options);
  const ethereum = MMSDK.getProvider();
  
  const [isInstalled, setIsInstalled] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const isMetaMaskInstalled = () => {
    return Boolean(ethereum && ethereum.isMetaMask);
  };

  const initialize = () => {
    //console.log(ethereum);
    console.log("Metamask esta instalado?: ", isInstalled);
    console.log("Metamask esta conectado?: ", isConnected);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    isMetaMaskInstalled();
    initialize();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

And here the error:

[image: Reference error: Window not defined]

I know there are some other explanations but none of them using Metamask SDK,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the MetaMask SDK in a server-side rendered application, you will need to use a different approach. One option is to use the `web3` library, which provides a programmatic interface for interacting with the Ethereum blockchain.

Here is an example I found in the internet of how you could use web3 in a server-side rendered Next.js application:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import web3 from 'web3';

const options = {
  defaultAccount: '0x0',
  defaultBlock: 'latest',
  defaultGas: 1,
  defaultGasPrice: 1,
  transactionBlockTimeout: 50,
  transactionConfirmationBlocks: 24,
  transactionPollingTimeout: 480,
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const provider = new web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
    );
    const web3Instance = new web3(provider);

    // Now you can use the web3 instance to interact with the Ethereum blockchain
  }, []);

  return <div>My Component</div>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

This example shows how to create a `web3` instance that connects to the Ethereum mainnet using the [Infura](https://www.infura.io) API.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this one!

Comment: You are welcome, please let me know if that's helps!

Comment: Yes it worked, I even used the web3 component taking my Metamask wallet as provider, thanks very much Omar!.

Comment: Sounds great :)